# After updating Meta Description of my blogs, would google recrawl it in some time or do I have request re-indexing?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have published a few blogs that have value to offer it's receiving significant impressions on Google SERP but not influencing CTR, so my question is after updating meta description would google automatically crawl the new Meta Description & display it on SERP or do I have to request indexing from GSC

Comment: They regularly crawl sites. They'll find these changes next time they do a crawl.

Comment: What John said, they will come back at some time. You can request indexing of you want to try and speed things up.